# Let : $\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{(x+x^2)}=f(x),x>0$ then the minimum over $(0,\infty)$ verify a particular power series

Tags: power-series, examples-counterexamples, maxima-minima, gamma-function, pi

Problem :

Let :

$$\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{(x+x^2)}=f(x),x>0$$

Then let $A=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4}}-1$ And $y$ be the global minimum over $x\in (0,\infty)$ of $f(x)$ then it seems we have :

$$2+A-A^4-30A^6-103A^8-76A^{10}-23A^{12}-22A^{14}-3A^{16}-\cdots=y\tag{I}$$

I cannot pursue it because of the floating point in computer but I have a Conjecture:

Conjecture :

> > Starting from $-3A^{16}$ all the coefficient in absolute value are less than $100$.

Update :

A similar series is :

$B=0.4616321944\cdots!$ be the minimum of  $\Gamma(x+1),x>0$ then it seems we have :

$$y=1+B+2(B-1)^4+20(B-1)^6+\cdots$$

---

---

> > Why it's interesting:

The related inequality :

$$h(x)=\Gamma(x)\geq f(y)(x+1)=h'(y)(x-y)+h(y)$$

Which says there is no other form of this kind .

I think we need a second point as we have :

$$\arcsin(\int_{0}^{1}t!dt×x)=q(x),\Gamma(x+1)=h(x+1)$$

Then :

### $$|q(A+1)-h(A+1)|<4×10^{-5}$$

---

> A strategy :

We have :

$$(x+1)^2\psi(x+2)+(x+1)(\psi(x+2)-2)-1=F(x),F(y-1)=0$$

Where $\psi$ is the digamma function .

Then as the derivative is positive for the truncated sum $I$ we can use Bernstein's polynomials with a faster converging series than the classical Bernstein's polynomials.
Then use Bürmann theorem

---

---

> > Question :

How to (dis)prove the conjecture ?

Reference :

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernsteinPolynomial.html

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BuermannsTheorem.html

Comment: Is there any particular reason that let you think that the conjecture is true?

Comment: The new update looks even more strange, because $1+B+96(B-1)^4+60(B-1)^6\approx 11$, whereas $y\approx 1.88599$.

Comment: It still looks not OK, because $1+B+2(B-1)^4+20(B-1)^6\approx 2.1166$, and this is even a worse approximation of $y\approx 1.88599$ than $1+B+2(B-1)^4\approx 1.6296$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$z=2+A-A^4-30A^6-103A^8-76A^{10}-23A^{12}-22A^{14}-3A^{16}.$$
As I understood the conjecture, it states that there exists a sequence $(c_n)_{n=9}^\infty$ of integers of absolute value less that $100$ such that $z+\sum_{n=9}^\infty c_nA^{2n}=y$,
that is $y-z=\sum_{n=9}^\infty c_nA^{2n}$. Since $A^2>\frac 1{99}$, it is
easy to show that the set of real numbers representable in the form $\sum_{n=9}^\infty c_nA^{2n}$ is the segment $[-C,C]$, where $C=\sum_{n=9}^\infty 99A^{2n}=\frac{99A^{18}}{1-A^2}$.
(In fact, to represent the numbers from $[-C,C]$ it suffices to use only sequences $(c_n)_{n=9}^\infty$
with nonpositive or nonnegative members). So the conjecture is equivalent to $|y-z|\le C$. I expect the latter inequality can be checked if we calculate $y$ and $z$ sufficiently precise.